# Xpath: evaluate condition at parent node along with filtering duplicate entries

Tags: xpath, xslt

Need an Input on the below XPath requirement:

XML:

```
<component>
    <Bundle>
        <entry>
            <resource>
                <Condition>
                    <id value="123456"/>
                </Condition>
            </resource>
            <search>
                <mode value="match"/>
            </search>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <resource>
                <Condition>
                    <id value="123456"/>
                </Condition>
            </resource>
            <search>
                <mode value="match"/>
            </search>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <resource>
                <Condition>
                    <id value="654321"/>
                </Condition>
            </resource>
            <search>
                <mode value="include"/>
            </search>
        </entry>        
    </Bundle>   
</component>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:with-param name="entries" select="//Bundle/entry/resource/Condition[not(id/@value=following::Condition/id/@value)]"/>
```

Currently it is eliminating duplicate condition entries. Now need to enhance it to
consider `<entry>` with `<mode value="match"/>` and its respective conditions only.

tried with different approaches likes `//Bundle/entry[<<expression>>]/resource/Condition[not(id/@value=following::Condition/id/@value)]` and `//Bundle/entry/resource/Condition[not(id/@value=following::Condition/id/@value) and ../../<<expression>>]`
Not giving expected result. Any input will be helpful.

expected output:

```
<Condition>
    <id value="123456"/>
</Condition>
```

want only conditions which are not duplicates as well as matching `<mode value="match"/>` only.

Comment: What would look like your desired output/nodeset?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add (at least) the expected result - see [mcve]. In general, the method you use to eliminate duplicates is very inefficient. If - as it seems - you are limited to XSLT 1.0, use the [Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example of [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="entry[search/mode/@value='match']" use="resource/Condition/id/@value" />

<xsl:template match="/component">
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Bundle/entry[search/mode/@value='match'][count(. | key('k1', resource/Condition/id/@value)[1]) = 1]/resource/Condition"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <Condition>
    <id value="123456"/>
  </Condition>
</output>
```

---

In **XSLT 2.0** or higher, you could reduce this to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/component">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(Bundle/entry[search/mode/@value='match']/resource/Condition/id/@value)">
            <Condition>
                <id value="{.}"/>
            </Condition>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: michael.hor257k, XSLT 1.0 is working as expected. Could you modify 2.0 solution where i have pass the Condition itself to another template which will be further processing of selected condition.

Comment: No, not unless you provide a [mcve]. Again in general, if you want to preserve the original nodes, you can use `xsl:for-each-group` to remove the duplicates  And of course Muenchian grouping works in XSLT 2.0 too, though it's very rarely required.

Comment: @WApp Why can't you pass the distinct values of Condition/id/@value as the parameter? What other information do you need to get from the Condition?

Comment: Entire condition resource is required in the template and we will process it as section in output with many fields consumed from the Condition.